# how to resize an image so it shows in its entirety within an object?

Tags: uv, image

lets take a 3d rectangle add a image to only one side of it, after unwrapping it. Using nodes, adding an image that will show bigger then that objects face. the image appears on the selected face of the object, but it is way too big to show the entire image on the selected face. How do I go about resizing the image so it shows one image within the selected face of the object?

[image]

[image]

updated file

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### UV Unwrapping

The best thing to do would be to start with a blank cube, then select **only** the face that you want to have the car. Key <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> to enter *Orthographic View*, and then key either <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> (whichever makes you face the selected face). Key <kbd>U</kbd> and select *Project from View (Bounds)*.

[image]

### Node-based Mapping

[image]

The .blend file for the second result:

[image]

Comment: Like I STATED before this is an 3D object not a single plane ja. your solution does not work. check your moded file I added to my question.

Comment: @uxserx-bw sorry. 3-D rectangle instead of cube confused me. i'll fix my answer.

Comment: Just ike I wrote it, you changed it to single plane, I changed it back becuase I wrote it to state what I was talking about. 3D not 2D.

Answer (score 0):

In the UV editor, you can adjust the UV map coordinates by size, scale, rotation, etc, just like you can with meshes in the 3D viewer. The hotkeys are the same.

The UV editor shows your whole image, and by default will allow you to position your UV map coordinates outside of the image bounds so that you can have repeating patterns. You can constrain the UV mapping coordinates to just the image bounds by going into the UV menu and selecting Constrain to Image Bounds.

Once you've done that, you can click on each corner of the UV map coordinates and pull them to their respective corners of the image. Now your whole image will cover the face(s) you mapped.

Comment: maybe it is the way I am unwrapping it. (nubie here) select cube, edit mode, U - then select the first one "Unwrap" it gives me the one side each within the UV editor, I add Image, I have all sides witht the complete image showing on all sides. I do not know how to get to constraints other then what I seen in the dropdown menu. Adding what I've done to my orginal post blend file. I've tried smart unwrap too

Comment: time to go watch some more youtube video on UV mapping I suppose. :D

Comment: OK I figured out one way of doing it using a cube. now back to my project to try it out on that. I unwrapped it, then selected just one "face" using edge select then unwrapped it from the cube, created a new materal then added a inage texture then added the image to that, it now shows only on one face of the cube.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured out one way of doing it using a cube. now back to my project to try it out on that. I unwrapped it, then selected just one "face" using edge select then unwrapped it from the cube, created a new materal then added a inage texture then added the image to that, it now shows only on one face of the cube.

one can also just take the "cube" and edge only one face of it, mark edges, then U -> unwrap then in nodes add a materal then add the image texture, then add your image you want to only show on that one face of the "cube". 3D rectangle etc...

here is the solution

[image]